# Bash filter out files with a given extension

Tags: bash, git, rubocop

I've added a pre-commit hook to run Rubocop against any files that are being staged for commit. However, Rubocop errors out when you give it a .png or .svg file.  I've added those file extensions to the `exclude` block in `.rubocop.yml` but because I'm actually explicitly supplying files by name that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Here's my pre-commit script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

git diff --staged --diff-filter=d --name-only | xargs bundle exec rubocop
```

I think the approach is grabbing the list of files from that git command and looping through them, filtering out any that are .png or .svg, but honestly I don't know how to do that.  Any suggestions on filtering the files by extension?

Comment: BTW, to make GNU `xargs` reliably do the right thing with line-oriented input even when your filenames contain literal whitespace, quotes, escapes, etc., use `-d $'\n'`. (With versions of xargs that don't have `-d`, one can need to transform newlines to NULs and use `xargs -0`; see [BashPitfalls #55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0) describing the issues).

Comment: BTW, if you're going to use `set -e` here (which is [not generally recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)), I'd suggest also using `set -o pipefail`. Right now, a failure in `git diff` won't necessarily be reflected in the exit status of the larger script. (It _can_, but that depends on how your version of `xargs` deals with the empty-input case, and that varies across implementations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea might be to filter out those extensions using `grep`.

```sh
git diff --staged --diff-filter=d --name-only \
  | grep --invert-match '\.\(png\|svg\)$' \
  | xargs bundle exec rubocop
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the `-E` argument to `grep` so you don't need as many escapes and aren't relying on GNU extensions to BRE. One could, f/e, use `grep -vE '[.](png|svg)$'` (granted, `[.]` is more characters than `\.`, but it's more consistent in how it's parsed across languages and quoting contexts, and IMHO easier to read).

Comment: That did the trick.  Much easier than looping and filtering.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag `--only-recognized-file-types` which I think will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff  --staged --diff-filter=d --name-only -- ':!*.png' ':!*.svg'
```

or for easier control you could check attributes and set up the matching just in `.gitattributes`.

Say `git help glossary` and hunt up `pathspec`, there's probably a quicker route to find the docs for it but that's the one I know.